# Mathematica cannot find a solution for `DSolve`

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

```
DSolve[{0.0225/((1 + 0.045/f[z]^2) f[z]^4) - 1/f[z]^3 + (
3.85274*10^6 f[z])/z^2 + (f^\[Prime]\[Prime])[z] == 0, f[0] == 1, 
f'[0] == 0}, {f[z]}, {z}]
(*DSolve[{0.0225/((1 + 0.045/f[z]^2) f[z]^4) - 1/f[z]^3 + (
3.85274*10^6 f[z])/z^2 + (f^\[Prime]\[Prime])[z] == 0, f[0] == 1, 
Derivative[1][f][0] == 0}, {f[z]}, {z}]*)
```

Why does'nt this work? Do I need to simplify this manually?

EDIT
I tried `NDSolve`

```
NDSolve[{(3.85274*10^6 f[z])/z^2 + 0.0225/(
0.045 f[z]^2 + f[z]^4) + (f^\[Prime]\[Prime])[z] == 1/f[z]^3, 
f[1] == 1, f'[1] == 1}, {f[z]}, {z, 1, 100}]
*({{f[z] -> InterpolatingFunction[{{1., 100.}}, <>][z]}}*)
```

I changed the value of `z` in the boundary conditions to avoid indefinite values. Plotting gives,

```
Plot[f, {z, 1, 100}]
```

[image: Plot]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why does'nt this work?

it is nonlinear ode. only few nonlinear ode's can be solved analytically. –

The Numerical solution is fine. It just oscillates rapidly. change the time scale to see it.

```
ode = 0.0225/((1 + 0.045/f[z]^2) f[z]^4) - 1/f[z]^3 + (3.85274*10^6 f[z])/z^2 + f''[z] == 0;
ode = Rationalize[ode]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 DSolve[ode, f[z], z]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ic = {f[1] == 1, f'[1] == 1}
sol = NDSolveValue[{ode, ic}, f, {z, 1, 1.005}];
Plot[sol[z], {z, 1, 1.005}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Just what I was looking for!!! Thanks